# array should not spit out on a screen php

Tags: php, mysql

I have made a form where user post data like names product and links. For validation I am using `FILTER_VALIDATE_URL`. Now what i want is after validation only host insert into database. like https://www.google.com. Only www.google.com insert in database. For doing this i am using

```
$website = var_dump(parse_url($websitex, PHP_URL_HOST));

$sql = "INSERT INTO test (Name, Contact, Product) Value ($name, $website, $product)
$result = mysqli_query($dbc_conn, $sql);
```

Now the problem the host data not going into database plus the host array show into the screen. What i want is only host data insert and array not show on the screen.

Comment: `var_dump` returns `void`, also your open to sql injections.

Comment: simple english please ..

Comment: RTM: http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php

Comment: Basically stop using `var_dump`, problem solved.

Comment: Just remove `var_dump()`.  It's not clear what you *thought* that function does, but the behavior you describe is exactly what it does.  You should also look into prepared statements with query parameters to address your SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: yes well for sql injection i didn't mention here mysql_real_escape.. any better solution

Comment: Okay let me check ..

Comment: @Ashley, `mysql_real_escape_string` is not a sufficient prevention.  Take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php

Comment: no .. array is still showing after submitting.
I am doing like this $website = parse_url($websitex, PHP_URL_HOST);.

Comment: @Ashley: Do you know what `parse_url()` returns?  https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php  It's an array.  Are you inserting *the array* into your SQL?  Or an element from the array?

Comment: At first i need to validate the link and then for inserting only host in database  thats why i used parse_url so as you said inserting an array into sql .. yes